# Move or Rename Files and Directories with mv

Tags: directory, file-rename, movefile

I've tried using:

```
mv filename destination path
```

Unfortunately, I am faced with an error message:

```
mv filename destination_path
mv: cannot stat 'filename': No such file or directory
```

How to I get this desired output?

```
mv path_to_file/filename destination_path    
input: mv filename destination_path
Output: mv: cannot stat 'filename': No such file or directory
```

Comment: You should have added the output of `ls`. If in `ls` you don't see the file, you are in the wrong directory. Please, read [How to ask good questions](https://zacanger.com/blog/posts/using-stackoverflow-effectively/) This have nothing to do with programming. Ask on https://superuser.com or https://askubuntu.com

Comment: This helped me look into the file folder, so thanks.